# .NET 5.0 API is working fine with AWS Services, but not working when dockerized

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, docker, .net-core, .net-5

I have developed an API in .NET 5.0 where I am using Amazan SQS and Elasticsearch. It works perfectly when I run it, but it gives me an exception:

```
No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured
```

This issue is happening only when I dockerized the API.
I have configured AWS Creds using CLI and accessing them as follows:

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
    services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions
            .Converters.Add(new StringConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    });
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddTransient<IQueService, SQSService>();
    services.AddTransient<IAmazonSQS, AmazonSQSClient>();
    services.AddTransient<IAmazonSimpleSystemsManagement, AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient>();
    
    services.AddElasticsearch(options => {
        options.Endpoint = Configuration.GetValue<string>(ConfigurationConstants.ES_URL);
        options.AWSOptions = Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
    });
}
```

Comment: how you configured aws credentials and region, this error is because of the aws keys and region not configured properly

Comment: I have configured using AWS CLI, and accessing them in startup class

Comment: check below retrieval gives a proper value, may be some problems with your configuration when deployed as container
Configuration.GetValue<string>(ConfigurationConstants.ES_URL);
try logging

Comment: its working fine without docker, but not working when dockerized